# titles not being displayed in MenuItems

Tags: android

I currently stuck with the problem that the Strings in my ListViews Context Menu are not being displayed. In the `onCreate` method I have used `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` and I am then doing the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (view == getListView()) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

        long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Item " + id);
        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.header_icon);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW, Menu.NONE, R.string.contextmenu_view);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_REMOVE, Menu.NONE, R.string.contextmenu_remove);

    }
}
```

When I run it, the HeaderTitle and the HeaderIcon are both working as expected and there are two rows in the context menu but both of them are empty. I've tried this with hard coded Strings as well but the same occurs.